# Using "hosts" file to redirect

Tags: redirection, hosts

Ok, I know how to redirect a normal page using the "host" file but it doesn't work for certain pages like 
http://rustledjimmies.com/
or
http://heyyeyaaeyaaaeyaeyaa.com/

For example, I want to redirect youtube.com to rustledjimmies.com/. But after I do the things I usually have done to redirect, it just doesn't work.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Here's an example which I have put into "hosts" file.

104.36.80.4 fb.com

The IP Adress is for the site rustledjimmies.com  but somehow when I write it into "hosts" it shows up a different website.

205.186.179.191 fb.com

This one is for the heyyeyaaeyaaaeyaeyaa.com but it doesn't respond at all (for me atleast)

Comment: Did you flush the dns cache on the workstation? cmd > `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you putting in your hosts file?  Please include the relevant lines in your original question.

Comment: I notice you've tried to edit from another account - please *register* an account and use the contact us link to get all three merged.

Answer (score 7):

It won't work for some sites.

Hosting one site per server (or per IP address) is not a good idea for small websites. Hosting multiple websites on one IP address is possible, this feature is called virtual hosts.

But the server has to somehow check which site you're willing to open. HTTP protocol specification defines has a `Host` header (which is mandatory since HTTP 1.1) which contains address of the website your browser is requesting. This header is used by the server to select appropriate virtual host.

---

Here's a normal request to YouTube:

- Enter `http://youtube.com` in the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Your computer queries DNS server to resolve `youtube.com` domain name to IP address.

  - DNS server's response: `46.28.247.104`
- Browser sends a HTTP request to `46.28.247.104`:

  ```
  GET / HTTP/1.1
  Host: youtube.com
  ```

  - Server at `46.28.247.104` recognizes `youtube.com` as its virtual host and serves it to you.

---

Now let's assume you've mapped `youtube.com` to `192.168.0.100` using the `hosts` file.

- Enter `http://youtube.com` in the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `youtube.com`'s IP is provided in `hosts` file, so no DNS lookup is required.

  - System tells browser that `youtube.com`'s address is `192.168.0.100`
- Browser sends a HTTP request to `192.168.0.100`:

  ```
  GET / HTTP/1.1
  Host: youtube.com
  ```

  - Server at `192.168.0.100` doesn't recognize `youtube.com` as its virtual host, so it responds with `404` error code.

Comment: +1 excellent use of examples when it works and when it does not